# Jenkins: how to specify jenkinsfile in multibranch project

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline, multibranch-pipeline

Using Jenkins for multi-platform mutibranch builds.

I have multiple Multibranch Pipeline projects (one for each platform, since each platform requires notably different build steps). I have one code repository with multiple branches (which is why Multibranch Pipeline projects makes sense).

I would like to have each Multibranch Pipeline project reference a different Jenkinsfile, rather than all trying to use the one with the filename "Jenkinsfile" that is located in the root of the repository.

[This resolved bug](https://issues.jenkins-ci.org/browse/JENKINS-34561) suggests that I should be able to do this, but I can't find any documentation outlining how to do this. Anyone know how I can go about doing this?

Thanks for your time!
Allen

Comment: What version of Jenkins are you running? Since it was merged in so recently, maybe it just isn't in the version that you're using?

Comment: That was it! Updating the multibranch plugin from version 2.14 to 2.16 fixed my problem: I can now configure the jenkinsfile in my Build Configuration for my multibranch project!

Comment: Excellent!  Also, I've been wanting this feature for a while, so I'm glad that I now know that this functionality exists.  I'll add an answer indicating the exact version that this was added in.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Upgrade the Pipeline Multibranch plugin to at least version 2.15.  From the changelog at https://wiki.jenkins.io/display/JENKINS/Pipeline+Multibranch+Plugin:

> 2.15 (Jun 01, 2017)
>
> - JENKINS-34561 Option to select a script name/path other than Jenkinsfile.

After that, you can go to your project's configuration page and access the setting shown below:

[image: Jenkinsfile path configuration]

Comment: I noticed someone else actually had the same question. You're welcome to grab those Answer points here as well if you'd like: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37272120/jenkins-workflow-multibranch-allow-for-specifying-jenkinsfile-path

Comment: Any ideas how to leverage this from a job-dsl multibranchPipelineJob definition?

Comment: if the desired name for the file was CheckmarxJenkinsfile then add this to the job-dsl for the multibranchPipelineJob

 configure { project ->
        (project / 'factory' / 'scriptPath') << 'CheckmarxJenkinsfile'
    }

Comment: Can you use environment variables inside that `Script Path`? I've tried `%BRANCH_NAME%/Jenkinsfile`, `BRANCH_NAME/Jenkinsfile`, etc. etc. to no avail.

Comment: @Cole try ${env.BRANCH_NAME}